# Remember values from form field for a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

I have "Page 1" and "Page 2".

On "Page 1" if I click on the button "Go To Page 2" I will get to "Page 2", also on "Page 1" I have a input field "This field right here" as placeholder.

On "Page 2" I have a button "Go Back To Page 1" that when I click it, it will bring me to "Page 1".

What I want is, after I click "Go Back To Page 1" to autocomplete the input "This field right here" with the submited value before I click on "Go To Page 2".

Bellow you have my current code:

**Page 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRandomPage () {
    document.getElementById('MyButton').onclick = location.href = "/?random=1";      
        };
</script>

<form>
<div class="checkboxes" align="center">
        <input type="hidden" name="random" value="1"><br>
        <input placeholder="This field right here" style="width: 296px; height: 30px;" type="text" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <label for="x"><input type="checkbox" id="x" checked=""><span> Some Text </span></label><br>
        <label for="y"><input type="checkbox" id="y" disabled=""><span> Some Text </span></label><br>
        <button id="MyButton" type="submit">Go To Page 2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Page 2**

```
<form action="/">
    <div align="center">
        <button type="submit">Go Back To Page 1</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm thinking maybe it could be done with js maybe? But I don't know how

Comment: Where is the rest of your javascript you wrote to try and do this?

Comment: this is generally done by storing data in server session

Comment: You can use html5 local/session storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) from HTML5, like below:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Answer (score 2):

To remember values you can use :

- HTML5 Storage like *localStorage* or *SessionStorage*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage
- cookie : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Use like that :

```
localStorage.variable = "saveMe";
```